# ruby command to split the output and check for a condition

Tags: ruby

I have written a ruby script to connect to oracle database and it gets the output in the format below, I want to know how to split the output and check for condition (IF split.value>90) when the table space size is above 90% 
then display critical message

```
  def exec_query
  stdin, stdout, stderr  = Open3.popen3("sqlplus -S  user/pwd@dbname")
  stdin.puts "tablespace script query here;"
  stdin.close
  puts "query executd"
  out = []
  until stdout.eof? do
  -- added code val=out.map(&:split).select {|_,v| v.to_f > 90}
  tmp = stdout.gets.chomp.strip
  puts tmp
  out.push tmp unless tmp.empty?
  end

  -- added code edit 2
  if val > 90
  puts "criticial"
  end:q1

  stdout.close
  stderr.close
```

Output

```
TABLESPACE_NAME          PERCENTAGE_USED
------------------------------ ---------------
SYSTEM           98.46
SYSAUX           95.15
USERS           9.32
UNDOTBS1           3.5
UNDOTBS2          2.93
TEMP
```

Edit 1:

after the output , i added a line to check if the value is above 90 it should send a critical message, but im getting this error

```
if val > 90
puts "criticial"
end:q1
```

Error Message

```
    test3.rb:34:in `exec_query': undefined method `>' for [["SYSTEM",     "98.46"],    [.    "SYSAUX", "95.15"]]:Array (NoMethodError)
from test3.rb:41:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does `out.map(&:split).select {|_,v| v.to_f > 90}` work for you?

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky , that narrows it down to this output ,

SYSTEM
98.46
SYSAUX
95.15

Comment: @engineersmnky , after the output , i added a line to check if the value is above 90 it should send a critical message, but im getting this error 



if val > 90
puts "criticial"
end:q1

Comment: The result of what I provided is the tables above 90 just display the message unless that result is `empty?`

Comment: @engineersmnky the result is perfect, i wanted to use the output of the result and then add an If statement and send a message, which im running into error, I have added in the update now

Comment: `v.to_f > 90` is your "if statement"

Comment: Note, you can use the [ruby-oci8](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8) gem to connect to Oracle. Much simpler than via the `sqlplus` command line. No need to parse the output.

Comment: @Schwern thank you , i did try writing in OCI8 , it is indeed easier and faster but due to some restriction  in our environment we had  to avoid OCI8 and write this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we have the output from the query, this is a straightforward parsing problem.

Here I've simulated the output using a string, [`stdout.each_line`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-each_line) works just as well.

```
output = %q[TABLESPACE_NAME          PERCENTAGE_USED
------------------------------ ---------------
SYSTEM           98.46
SYSAUX           95.15
USERS           9.32
UNDOTBS1           3.5
UNDOTBS2          2.93
TEMP
]

# Skip the first two header lines and get an iterator for the rest.
iter = output.each_line.drop(2)

# Iterate through each line with a hash to collect all the stats.
stats = iter.each_with_object({}) { |line,hash|
  # Split the line on whitespace.
  line.split(/\s+/, 2).each_slice(2) { |k,v|
    # Store the key/value pair after stripping the newline and converting to a Float
    hash[k] = v.chomp.to_f
  }
}

# Now do whatever you want with the resulting Hash of stats.
# {"SYSTEM"=>98.46, "SYSAUX"=>95.15, "USERS"=>9.32, "UNDOTBS1"=>3.5, "UNDOTBS2"=>2.93, "TEMP"=>0.0}

puts "Running out of space" if stats.any? { |_,v| v > 90 }
```

You can find most of the methods I used in the [Enumerable module](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while).

Comment: Thank you @schwern that works, one more thing i wanted to check is that, how can I also display the variable eg : system : 98.46  also in the last puts statment which is above 90 ? does "  puts v " work ? or

Comment: also i ran into errors when iwanted to give a clause in between v >80 & v<90 , may be im mnissing the syntax

Comment: @anudeepks `stats` is a Hash of key/value pairs. `stats["SYSTEM"]` will give you the value 98.46. Logical and in Ruby is `&&` so `80 < v && v < 90`. Or you can use a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F), `(80..90).include?(v)`. This is basic Ruby syntax, I recommend you review the basics like [Programming Ruby](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) and [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/).